Flutter: Override back button behaviour using PopScope
In flutter, when the user uses the back button, I want it to show a dialog to confirm they want to leave the page
I did this before using the following code:
AppScaffold(
      body: WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
            showLogoutDialog(context);
            return false;
        },
        child: Contents(),
      ),
);

As WillPopScope is now deprecated, how would I do this using the new PopScope, or any other method?
PopScope has a canPop property, and onPopInvoked which the documentation metions:
method is called; the pop has already happened. Use [canPop] to
disable pops in advance.


You can use PopScope like this here is the example code
PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
        final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
        final bool? shouldPop = await _showBackDialog(context);
        if (shouldPop ?? false) {
          navigator.pop();
        }
      },
    child: YourScreen(),
)


Here is the dialog code.
 Future<bool?> _showBackDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text("Are you sure?"),
          content: const Text(
            "Do you want to go back?",
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
              },
              child: const Text("No"),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              },
              child: const Text("Yes"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

Read more about the Migration guide here
